# "npm run" commands fail on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, webpack

I am using Windows PowerShell ISE with administrator privileges. My project uses webpack, which is installed as a local dependency with npm. I have a "script" defined in package.json:

`"build": "webpack --progress --config resources/assets/build/webpack.config.js",`

When I execute `npm run build` I get the error message `'webpack' is not recognized as an internal or external command`, but if I copy the webpack command and execute that it works fine. I'm not going to list my whole system PATH here, but it includes `.\node_modules\.bin` at the beginning. Clearly Windows has no problem finding webpack but Node for some reason can't.

I tried running `npm run build` in a privilege-less Command Line, no difference. I upgraded to the latest versions of Node and npm (13.0.1 and 6.12.1, respectively), to no avail. I even tried prefixing the command in package.json with `./node_modules/.bin/` but that didn't work.

Please don't suggest that I install webpack globally as that is not a real solution. Node is giving me this error with all locally-installed commands, not just webpack. I should be able to run commands locally through npm.

Comment: try rebooting your pc and give a try

Answer (score 0):

if you're using a recent version of npm, you can try

```sh
npx webpack ....
```

alternatively, you can install webpack locally and specify the exact path

```sh
node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js ....
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I had to bite the bullet and install webpack globally.